# How to avoid decoding the queryParams in Angular using CustomSerializer

Tags: angular, url-routing, angular2-routing, query-string

I am accessing Angular application with below URL queryParams strategy

When I try to access http://localhost:4200/test?url=http://abc/item%2F2/3, Angular is encoding queryParams hence I have used CustomUrlSerializer to decode them back as below but I wanted to retain the same queryParam without encoding or decoding

But currently the url decoded and shows as http://localhost:4200/test?url=http://abc/item/2/3 in the browser URL

But I want to URL to remain same i.e. http://localhost:4200/test?url=http://abc/item%2F2/3

Can some one provide me the better solution to handle this case?

```js
import {UrlSerializer, UrlTree, DefaultUrlSerializer} from '@angular/router';

export class MyUrlSerializer implements UrlSerializer {
    public ds = new DefaultUrlSerializer();

    parse(url: any): UrlTree {
        return this.ds.parse(url);
    }

    serialize(tree: UrlTree): any {
        const serializedUrl = this.ds.serialize(tree);
        return serializedUrl
            .replace(/%40/gi, '@')
            .replace(/%3A/gi, ':')
            .replace(/%24/gi, '$')
            .replace(/%2C/gi, ',')
            .replace(/%3B/gi, ';')
            .replace(/%20/gi, '+')
            .replace(/%3D/gi, '=')
            .replace(/%3F/gi, '?')
            .replace(/%2F/gi, '/');
    }
}
```

Slick Grid Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-fm1xua

Comment: Why do you want to allow such characters in your app's url? Do you user it outside of angular app? What is your use case?

Answer (score 4):

Once you send any special character through browser query string param URL, it gets encode/decode automatically by `encodeURIComponent` or `decodeURIComponent`. Both are javascript global functions.

You could handle it like:

```js
const myUri = 'http://abc/item/2/3';

const myEncodedUri = encodeURIComponent(myUri);
console.log(myEncodedUri);
// http%3A%2F%2Fabc%2Fitem%2F2%2F3

const myDecodedUri = decodeURIComponent(myEncodedUri);
console.log(myDecodedUri);
// http://abc/item/2/3
```

Comment: No I think you didn't understand my issue, I have created the demo page Slick Grid Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-fm1xua

If you see this link when you click on the Router Parameters you see how the URL changes to encoded in the URL

Comment: Thank you for sharing a code example. However, what is the expected result? Also, I have changed my answer. Let's see if it helps. Cheers